# Multiple aligned equations with one compact label

Tags: equations, citing, indexing, subequations

I would like implement a consistent way to mark my equations as follows:

```
a=a,    b=b,    c=c    (1a,b,c)
```

and to be able to cite every single equation independently, as for instance:

```
Equations (1) including Equation (1.b).
```

So far, I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, titlepage, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:test}
    a=a,\quad b=b,\quad c=c \tag{\theequation a,b,c}
\end{equation}
Equations \eqref{eq:test} including \eqref{eq:test:b}
\end{document}
```

The global equation with the global index *eq:text* works fine, but obviously I cannot use references of each sub equation. I don't think this is the way to go so I am open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something. It seems to work, but I'm not an expert so I would not expect this solution to be the best. Basically, I defined a `multequation` environment, which is essentially an `equation` environment with a modified tag. It takes two arguments:

1. (optional) The label of the equation. This is also used to define labels for subequations: if `#1` is the label, then subequations are labelled as `#1:a`, `#1:b` and so on.
2. The number of subequations.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{multeqlength}
\newcounter{multeqcntr}
\def\make@multeq@tagandlabels{%
    \edef\eq@tag{\alph{multeqcntr}}
    \ifnum\value{multeqcntr}<\value{multeqlength}
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\multeqtag\expandafter{\eq@tag,\,}
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\multeqlabels\expandafter{\eq@tag,}
        \stepcounter{multeqcntr}
        \make@multeq@tagandlabels
    \else
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\multeqtag\expandafter{\eq@tag}
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\multeqlabels\expandafter{\eq@tag}
    \fi%
}
\newenvironment{multequation}[2][]{%
    \setcounter{multeqlength}{#2}
    \setcounter{multeqcntr}{1}
    \def\multeqtag{\theequation}
    \def\multeqlabels{}
    \make@multeq@tagandlabels
    \begin{equation}
    \refstepcounter{equation}
    \tag{\multeqtag}
    \def\temp{#1}
    \ifx\temp\empty\else
        \label{#1}
        \@for\next:=\multeqlabels\do{%
            \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
                \string\newlabel{#1:\next}{{\theequation\next}{\thepage}}%
            }%
        }
    \fi%
}{
    \end{equation}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{multequation}[eq:test]{3}
    a=a,\quad b=b,\quad c=c
\end{multequation}
Equations \eqref{eq:test} including \eqref{eq:test:b}

\begin{multequation}{2}
    d=d, \quad e=e
\end{multequation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems brilliant! Your snippet works in Overleaf however I cannot integrate it in my project; What I did:
- Include amsmath and copy \makeatletter ... \makeatother in my preamble;
- copy the first multequation examples you gave
If I compile once, it shows "Equations(??) including (??) without errors. If I compile twice, I get the following error at that same line (I slightly changed the labels because I thought I already had a `eq:test`):
`Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }. ...ef{eqq:test} including \eqref{eqq:test:b}`

Comment: I get a second error right after the first one: `Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete. ...ef{eqq:test} including \eqref{eqq:test:b}`. I finally get a 3rd error: `Extra \else. \include{chapters/plasticity}` (my snippet is in plasticity.tex, itself included in main.tex where the preamble is).

Comment: I am no expert in LaTeX, and I am confused as to why the MWE works. Actually the MWE you provided also works if I reproduce my file structure: snippet in test.tex, itself included in main.tex... Oh and I don't think it matters but I use `TeXstudio 3.0.1 (git 3.0.1)
Using Qt Version 5.12.1, compiled with Qt 5.12.1 R`

Comment: The errors refer to the line:    `\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\newlabel{#1:\next}{{\theequation\next}{}}%
   }%`

Comment: @CremaDeLimon From the error you're getting, I suspect it has something to do with `hyperref`. I added `hyperref` to my example and it compiles fine, although with a warning telling me that no link is created for equation (1b). I'm afraid I can't really help you without seeing your code.

Comment: It's okay, the problem has to do with my project. In the meantime, I found another solution that I will post in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am coming back with what seems to be answering my problem. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\advancethree}[3]{%
    \stepcounter{equation}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation}\label{#1}%
    \edef\temp{\theequation,}%
    %
    \stepcounter{equation}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation}\label{#2}%
    \edef\hehe{b}
    \edef\temp{\temp\hehe,}%
    %
    \stepcounter{equation}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation}\label{#3}%
    \edef\hehe{c}
    \edef\temp{\temp\hehe}%
    %
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\temp}%
}
\let\ORItheequation\theequation
\newcommand{\restore}{\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\let\theequation\ORItheequation}
\newenvironment{supermega}[2][]{
    \subequations
    \label{#1}
    \advancethree{#1:a}{#1:b}{#1:c}%
    \begin{equation}
}{
    \end{equation}\restore
    \endsubequations
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{supermega}[eqq:test]{3}
    a=a,\quad b=b,\quad c=c, 
\end{supermega}
equation \eqref{eqq:test}, including \eqref{eqq:test:b}
\end{document}
```

I adapted an example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341922/manual-tag-without-amsmath). It's barely a tinkered working solution, and it's adapted only to the "a,b,c" case. I am still looking for a more general and elegant solution.